# Beginner frustration from WPF, esp. on Data Binding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding

First of all, I really am a beginner. I mostly worked on WinForm, so I never heard of Data Binding such on WPF.

Tried to learn from blogs and MSDN, but I just can't get a grasp. Data Binding is only one of my confusion on WPF, but it is the major thing I need to understand right now.

Say I got these class : 
    CustomerDL.vb (Data Access Layer)
    CustomerBL.vb (Business Layer)
    FormCustomer.xaml (Presentation Layer)

What I do now, is the only concept I ever learn : DL -> BL -> PL.

Here is my PL :

```
Public Class FrmEmployee2
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        MasterEmployeeBL = New MasterEmployeeBL
        Employees = MasterEmployeeBL.FetchAllEmployee()

        MainGrid.DataContext = Employees
    End Sub

    Private _employees As List(Of Employee)
    Public Property Employees() As List(Of Employee)
        Get
            Return _employees
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of Employee))
            _employees = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public MasterEmployeeBL As MasterEmployeeBL
End Class
```

And this is my WPF :

```
<dx:DXWindow x:Class="FrmFindEmployee2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
    xmlns:dxlc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/layoutcontrol"
    xmlns:dxd="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/docking"
    xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors" 
    xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
    xmlns:dxgt="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid/themekeys"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BMT_WPF"
    dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="MetropolisDark"
    Title="Find Employee" Height="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WorkArea}, Path=Height}" Width="658"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" SizeToContent="Width">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:BooleanToStatusConverter x:Key="BoolToStatusConv" />
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/BMT-WPF;component/Helpers/EditStyles.xaml" />    
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" DataContext="{Binding Source=Employees}">
        <DockPanel>
            <dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoPopulateColumns="True">

            </dxg:GridControl>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</dx:DXWindow>
```

I assumed that this would be sufficient to bind Employees List to my GridControl, but it shows nothing.

Can anybody help to point out any good resources to where I can learn about WPF from a beginner's view?

Sorry for the long post. Cheers ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the DataContext of MainGrid twice, once in your code, and once in your XAML. I would recommend removing the XAML binding on this element.

For  a basic tutorial on data binding, try this blogpost I wrote:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/04/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-and-wp7-part-one/

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Can you explain to me, why would it be wrong when I declare the Data Context in both place?

And where would be more appropriate to set Data Context, xaml or behind code?